Removed comma in rgba when I run Prettier
This is very weird to me. But I face this problem when I ever I run prettier (yarn run prettier -- write) and commit the code.
We are using Prettier check before running the write command.
Before running the yarn Prettier:
rgba(14, 111, 249, .2)

After running the yarn prettier and commit
rgba(14 111 249 / .2)

Not sure why this is happening.
This is happening every time we try to run the command

I don't think the question is about [reactjs], [git] or [hadoop-yarn].
It's only about [prettier].

Well according to this post, prettier is working exactly how it should.
Edit -
If the post has been deleted or is not accessible, here's what was mentioned.
"In source code, stop using the old rgb()/hsl() CSS color syntax with commas.
Get used to the modern comma-free CSS color syntax, supported in all modern browsers."
Modern Color Function syntax
rgb(100% 0% 0% / 50%)
Legacy Color Function Syntax
rgba(100%, 0%, 0%, 0.5)

Note: The old syntax will continue to work


My advice is to copy text from the linked post to your answer. This way the text will be preserved if the post will be deleted, hidden, or even if the entire X destroyed.

Advice noted @phd !!
